# Android imagechanger dependent on variable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image, set

I'm making an app which measures the dB level of sound.
To support this value an image will be shown of a situation to which the sound level is comparable to. (eg: an image of a highway to show sound of about 100dB).

To change the images I wrote some if-statements that change the source of the imageview.

```
int pic=1;

// Imageview changer //

ImageView IconView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
TextView Sound = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dBTextView);
int Soundlvl = Integer.valueOf(Sound.getText().toString());

if( Soundlvl < 40)
{
    if(pic != 1){
        IconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.recycle49); 
        Log.i("LevelMeterActivity","****Switch image 1****");
        pic=1;
    }
}   

else if ( Soundlvl < 60)
{
    if(pic != 2){
        IconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.two220);
        Log.i("LevelMeterActivity","****Switch image 2****");
        pic=2;
    }
}

else if ( Soundlvl < 80)
{
    if(pic !=3){
        IconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.television4);
        Log.i("LevelMeterActivity","****Switch image 3****");
        pic=3;
    }
}

else if ( Soundlvl < 100)
{
    if(pic !=4){
        IconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.highway2);
        Log.i("LevelMeterActivity","****Switch image 4****");
        pic=4;
    }   
}

else if ( Soundlvl < 120)
{
    if(pic !=5){
        IconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.construction);
        Log.i("LevelMeterActivity","****Switch image 5****");
        pic=5;

    }       
}

else if ( Soundlvl < 1000)
{
    if(pic !=6){
        IconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.impaired);
        pic=6;
        Log.i("LevelMeterActivity","****Switch image 6****");
    }       
}
```

The code stops working after 1 loop. I checked it without the if statements and then it works fine so the problem should be in here. Am I using the correct way to set the images? The images change quite fast so maybe that causes it to stop..